# What is one-one $C^1$ mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

When I was reading complex analysis by Joseph Bak Newman I came across the word one one $C^1$  mapping. What is it? Is it same as one one mapping? It came in the definition of smooth curves. The text does not explain the notation.

Comment: $C^1$ just means continuous.

Answer (score 3):

$C^1$ means continuously differentiable.  In general $C^k$ means the function has $k$ derivatives and they are all continuous functions.  A continuous function is then $C^0$ in this notation.

Usually for defining paths in complex analysis, people take a $C^1$ function $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to {\mathbb{C}}$.  That means that $\gamma'$ exists and is a continuous function.  This is useful for integration, as when you integrate along $\gamma$, with respect to $dz$, then the $dz$ becomes $\gamma'(t)dt$, so you want a continuous function under the integral.  That is, you define
$$
\int_\gamma f(z)\, dz = \int_0^1 f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt
$$
Notice that it is useful  to have both $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ to be continuous, since integrating continuous functions is no problem.